# Opening outlook in python/javascript/shell with an attachment in windows 64bits

Tags: python, email, outlook, thunderbird

I've been trying to open a mail client (does not have to be outlook) in windows with specified attachment

Using `mailto` option does not open with the attachment and using thunderbird commandline does not work in window machine.

Will there be any way to solve this problem (using any of the javascript/python/shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic way of doing that for all email clients, but for Outlook you can use a script (VBS) similar to the one below. JS or Python will be very similar.

```
set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set Item = App.CreateItem(0)
Item.Subject = "test"
Item.Attachments.Add "c:\temp\test.txt"
```

Comment: It helped me a lot!! Thank you so much

Comment: If  the reply answers you question, please mark it as such. Thank you!.